# Adding non-duplicated elements to existing keys in java 8 functional style

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap

I have a map I want to populate:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

with this method:

```
private void compute(String key, String[] parts) {
    myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> getMessage(parts));
}
```

`compute()` is invoked as follows:

```
for (String line : messages) {
    String[] parts = line.split("-");
    validator.validate(parts); //validates parts are as expected
    String key = parts[parts.length - 1];

    compute(key, parts);
}
```

`parts` elements are like this:

```
[AB, CC, 123]
[AB, FF, 123]
[AB, 456]
```

In the `compute()` method, as you can see I am trying to use the last part of the element of the array as a `key` and the other parts to be used as `values` for the map I am looking to build.

My Question: How do I add to existing key only the unique values using Java 8 functional style e.g.

```
{123=[AB, FF, CC]}
```

Comment: I assume you're using a `Map<String, String[]>`, right? If so, why don't you use a `Map<String, Set<String>>` or `Map<String, SortedSet<String>>` instead?

Comment: You want to add a value to an array associated to an existing key only if that value doesn't exist in the array already, correct?

Comment: @Thomas edited post to add Map info. map is `Map<String, Set<String>>`

Comment: @dabadaba add value to a `set` associate with key if exists or add a new key and populate if doesnt exist already.

Comment: Have a look at the JavaDoc example on `computeIfAbsent`: `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<V>()).add(v);` and adapt it - you're creating a new set if it doesn't exist and otherwise add a new value. Then just add all array elements except the last, e.g. by converting those to a list and calling `addAll(list)`.

Comment: You are not removing the last element (the key) from the values. Or do you inside the `getMessage` method you didn’t post?

Comment: @Holger I removed `getMessage()` and now iterating `parts` array passing each part (except last) to `compute()` which now has a body `instructionsMapped.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(part);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested I added a lambda variant, which just adds the parts via lambda to the map in the `compute`-method:

```
private void compute(String key, String[] parts) {
  myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, 
    s -> Stream.of(parts)
               .limit(parts.length - 1)
               .collect(toSet()));
}
```

But in this case you will only get something like `123=[AB, CC]` in your map. Use `merge` instead, if you want to add also all values which come on subsequent calls:

```
private void compute(String key, String[] parts) {
  myMap.merge(key, 
    s -> Stream.of(parts)
               .limit(parts.length - 1)
               .collect(toSet()),
               (currentSet, newSet) -> {currentSet.addAll(newSet); return currentSet;});
}
```

I am not sure what you intend with `computeIfAbsent`, but from what you listed as `parts` and what you expect as output, you may also want to try the following instead of the whole code you listed :

```
// the function to identify your key
Function<String[], String> keyFunction = strings -> strings[strings.length - 1];
// the function to identify your values
Function<String[], List<String>> valuesFunction = strings -> Arrays.asList(strings).subList(0, strings.length - 1);
// a collector to add all entries of a collection to a (sorted) TreeSet 
Collector<List<String>, TreeSet<Object>, TreeSet<Object>> listTreeSetCollector = Collector.of(TreeSet::new, TreeSet::addAll, (left, right) -> {
  left.addAll(right);
  return left;
});

Map myMap = Arrays.stream(messages) // or: messages.stream()
  .map(s -> s.split("-"))
  .peek(validator::validate)
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(keyFunction,
      Collectors.mapping(valuesFunction, listTreeSetCollector)));
```

Using your samples as input you get the result you mentioned (well, actually sorted, as I used a TreeSet).

```
String[] messages = new String[]{
                "AB-CC-123",
                "AB-FF-123",
                "AB-456"};
```

produces a map containing:

```
123=[AB, CC, FF]
456=[AB]
```

Last, but not least: if you can, pass the key and the values themselves to your method. Don't split the logic about identifying the key and identifying the values. That makes it really hard to understand your code later on or by someone else.

Comment: could you change your answer to remove the `splitting` as I am splitting first `String[] parts = line.split("-"); valid.validate(parts);` before passing `parts` to method that has the body from your answer

Comment: (Rephrased comment); Do you want to have a complete list of all possible values in the map after calling `getMessage(parts)`? If so, I can not recommend it.

Comment: I am no longer using `getMessage(parts`. Once `parts` is constructed after the `splitting`, `parts` is validated. From there on, the intention is to pass `parts` to `compute(parts)` which should populate the map with unique values against the corresponding key.

Comment: Is my assumption right, that the messages array holds the contents as follows: `new String[]{"AB-CC-123", "AB-FF-123", "AB-456"};`? If so, you will never get all the values into the map as long as you use `computeIfAbsent` (except you do something that is not advisable ;-)).

Comment: I added two variants (1 for computeIfAbsent and 1 for merge) to add the `parts` via lambda expressions. Also added the validation in the complete-computation-variant. If you aren't doing expensive computations or validations you might also want to consider to do the complete computation beforehand (as shown in the first example).

Answer (score 1):

To add more parts to a possibly existing key you're using the wrong method; you want `merge()`, not `computeIfAbsent()`.

If `validator.valudate()` throws a checked Exception, you must call it outside a stream, so you'll need a foreach loop:

```
for (String message : messages) {
    String[] parts = message.split("-");
    validator.validate(parts);
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(parts));
    String key = list.getLast();
    list.removeLast();
    myMap.merge(key, new HashSet<>(list), Set::addAll);
}
```

Using a `LinkedList`, which has methods `getLast()` and `removeLast()`, makes the code very readable.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>

Comment: `Set::addAll));` complains float is not a functional interface. Know why that is and what it should be replaced with? also what if `validate()` throws exception? would the above change in anyway?

Comment: can you update the answer as bad return type in method ref..cannot convert boolean to Set. Also validate throws custom exceptions which extends Exception so how to handle with the lambda?

Comment: @user2781389 if validate throws a checked Exception, then you can't call it from a stream - that's a language rule. I've modified the code to cater for that, and the result is much more readable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void compute(String[] parts) {
    int lastIndex = parts.length - 1;
    String key = parts[lastIndex];
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList(parts).subList(0, lastIndex);
    myMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).addAll(values);
}
```

Or if you want, you can replace the entire loop with a stream:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> myMap = messages.stream()     // if messages is an array, use Arrays.stream(messages)
        .map(line -> line.split("-"))
        .peek(validator::validate)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                parts -> parts[parts.length - 1],
                parts -> new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(parts).subList(0, parts.length - 1)),
                (a, b) -> { a.addAll(b); return a; }));
```

Comment: ` parts -> parts[parts.length - 1],` this doesnt compile with message `Array type expected and following line cannot resolve the constructor

Comment: @user2781389 works fine for me. What compiler are you using?